# show that two functions are the same almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose
$$\int^0_{-\infty} f(y+x)\,dx = \int^0_{-\infty}g(y+x)\,dx $$
for almost every $y$. Can I show that $f(y+x) = g(y+x)$ almost everywhere?

I assume that both terms are integrable and finite for all $y$. Also, $f(x+y)$ and $g(x+y)$ are differentiable wrt $x$ and $y$.

Comment: At least you would have to assume that both sides are finite.

Comment: @Cettt editted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(y) =\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(y+x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^y f(t)\,dt,\quad G(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} g(y+x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^y g(t)\,dt$$
By continuity of $f$ and $g$, these are continuous functions of $y$. Them being equal a.e, together with the continuity, implies that they're equal everywhere.

Now, apply the FTC: since $F(y)=G(y)$, $f(y)=F'(y)=G'(y)=g(y)$ for all $y$. Done.

Comment: is it not provable if I do not assume differentiability?

Comment: Continuity of $f$ and $g$ is plenty. Without that... [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).

Comment: Continuity of $f$ and $g$ is irrelevant for continuity of $F$ and $G$. Differentiability of $F$ and $G$ is where you actually use that assumption.